# Is it possible to encrypt the source of iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a webpage which has a iframe, textbox and button but nothing else... user types a URL to the textbox then clicks on the button. after that, URL is assined as the source of the iframe.

what happenes after is a java applet takes the screenshot of the webpage etc. etc.

What I discovered today, in Google Chrome, there is this option in the right click menu named "inspect element". With the help of this feature, user are likely to change whats inside of an iframe and manipulates the original data. Does anyone know how can I encrypt the source of iframe.

P.S. source of iframe is authenticated data.

This is what it look like [before manupilation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38860715/before.png)

This is [after manupilation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38860715/after.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "no". Html is a client-side SCRIPT language; while you may find ways to make things increasingly difficult to "manipulate", you ultimately have no ability to entirely prevent a user from seeing every single detail of what you are trying to do with 1 significant exception and that is the use of an applet or plugin (ie: flash, java, activex).

To help with your problem, if you are already using an applet, why not leverage that over using an iframe? You could also consider using the applet to generate a jpeg for delivery rather than HTML.

Comment: but how can I improve my java applet to display web pages like asd.com or some other pages end with .edu?

Comment: I don't have any experience with applets, but I would imagine that if its a plugin for a browser then just have the applet render whatever you want to show.

Comment: as far as I know, html can be displayed through applets, but when it comes to authenticated data... this is something else, impossible... I guess I am stuck once again...

Comment: I came up with the idea of disabling context menu on iframes which appears when you right click but before I change my question, I wanted to ask your permission since you answer my question OR I can select your answer as accepted answer and write new question with this idea of mine :) what do?

Comment: Accept and start a new one so if someone comes here with a similar question to your original one they will see this info. You can update your question with a link to your new one (at the end) for further reading.